# C# Copy inheritance hierarchy into string/enum format

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity-game-engine

In my game I have merchants. All items have a standard price. Each merchant has an interpretation of this price. I have an item inheritance hierarchy. `ConsumableItem` and `EquipableItem` inherits from the base class `GameItem`, HoldableEquipableItem inherits from EquipableItem and so on. A merchant can add a multiplier to one of these types, so if he has a multiplier of 0.5 on EquipableItem it means EquipableItem and all types inheriting from it will have their price multiplied with 0.5 (halved).

The inheritance hierarchy fits my problem since it doesn't have to be retyped anywhere and the tool `Type.IsSubclassOf` is built in available.But I'm not too fond of using types for game mechanics mainly because I want to show the type in the Unity inspector and it doesn't support Type, so I would have to use a string to symbolize it and parse the type afterward (maybe also 'ethical' and performance issues?).

Is there a good way I could implement this with a string or `enum` type instead of Type? A class where you had a method similar to `IsSubclassOf` just using string/enum instead. The type of the item could either be reflected through a field/property, or just convert `GetType` in the hierarchy to the string/enum version.

Comment: Can't you just add an enum/ string to your merchant base class and each subclass will set it accordingly?

Comment: GameItem class* and yes I could do that, but how do I implement the inheritance hierarchy with the enum? I'd prefer not to hard code it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to post this. Here is my solution to the problem if anyone needs it.

```
/// <summary>
/// Mimics the Type inheritance hierarchy for enums
/// </summary>
// Enum is a special class that cannot be used as a constraint, so instead use its parent interface IConvertible
public class InheritanceHierarchy<T> where T : IConvertible
{
    private Dictionary<T, InheritanceElement<T>> elements =
        new Dictionary<T, InheritanceElement<T>>();

    public void Add(T element, T parent)
    {
        var parentElement = parent.Equals(default(T)) ? null : elements[parent];
        elements.Add(element, new InheritanceElement<T>(element, parentElement));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add parent for multiple children
    /// </summary>
    public void Add(T parent, params T[] elements)
    {
        foreach (var element in elements)
            Add(element, parent);
    }

    public bool IsSameOrSubclass(T element, T parent)
    {
        return ParentIndex(element, parent) != -1;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get how many parents the element is from parent. If they don't relate return -1
    /// </summary>
    public int ParentIndex(T element, T parent)
    {
        // If the element is same as parent
        if (element.Equals(parent))
            return 0;
        // Loop through the chain of parents checking until it is either null or a match
        var actualParent = elements[element].parent;
        var parentIndex = 1;
        while (actualParent != null)
        {
            if (parent.Equals(actualParent.element))
                return parentIndex;
            else
            {
                actualParent = actualParent.parent;
                parentIndex++;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}

public class InheritanceElement<T> where T : IConvertible
{
    public T element;
    public InheritanceElement<T> parent;

    public InheritanceElement(T element, InheritanceElement<T> parent)
    {
        this.element = element;
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like this in your case:

```
public class GameItem {
    public List<string> Type { get; private set; }

    GameItem(List<string> type)
    {
        Type = type;
        Type.Add(nameof(GameItem))
    }

    public IsType(string type)
    {
        return Type.Contains(type);
    }

}

public class SubGameItem : GameItem
{
    public SubGameItem(List<string> type)
       : base(new List<string>(type){nameof(SubGameItem)})
    {
    }
}
```

If this is too hard coded for you, I will have to say I don't understand why, I think this is the least hardcoded way you can do to solve your issue, and it is probably better than using Type class.

If you don't have c#6, you will have to do it hardcoded, but I would use enums instead of string in that case (I would use enums anyway, but if you don't want have to make sure you updated the enum for each change, this is fine).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this implementation, thank you for the suggestion. What I'm wondering about is just how I would go about implementing `Type.IsSubclassOf` for the enum.

Comment: I updated it, 

The new implementation will work the way you want, however it will require you to make sure every subclass allows inserting previous subclass types, and that it adds its own type, which can cause some errors if you are not careful. If I think of a better way I will update it again